# vscode: assign keyboard shortcut to "Insert snippet" command

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

WHen I press ctrl-shift-p and type "insert snippet" a menu shows up with thhe available snippets

I'd like to assign ctrl-shift-q to that action, but I can't find the correspondent command.

Tried with

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+q",
        "command": "workbench.action.openSnippets"
    },
```

but a list of snipppets file appears instead of the list of snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. Try this action:

```
editor.action.showSnippets
```